# Writing File using System.IO.BinaryWriter

Tags: c#

I am trying to write an audio file using C#'s [`System.IO.BinaryWriter` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx).

It works fine when I perform this action:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\TestFile\File1", br.ReadBytes((int)br.BaseStream.Length));
```

However it does not work when I do the following:

```
Encoding e = Encoding.ASCII;
char[] reslts = e.GetChars(br.ReadBytes((int)br.BaseStream.Length));
br.BaseStream.Position = 0;
File.WriteAllBytes((@"C:\TestFile\File2",e.GetBytes(reslts));
```

I checked out the byte arrays, in both cases the array contained the same values ( I copied their value into a separate excel file and checked to see if there are any differences, there are none).

In both cases the base stream position is set to 0.

The code itself works, the file is created successfully. The problem occurs when I open the file, the first file works fine, the second file is not recognized by Windows Media Player.

Does anyone have any ideas of what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
Encoding e = Encoding.ASCII;
```

That looks suspicious. I know not of any audio format that is encoded using ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

Never, ever read arbitrary binary data as if it's text. It always goes wrong, because they're just not the same thing.

Also, don't rely on a stream's length - it could change, or it might not support fetching it anyway.

You want something like this:

```
public static byte[] CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16*1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

Then just open a `FileStream` to wherever you want to write the data, and call

```
CopyStream(inputStream, outputFile);
```

You haven't shown where you're getting the input from, but basically you don't really need the `BinaryReader`. It's not like you're using `BinaryReader` for its normal purpose, which is to read individual primitive values, length-prefixed strings etc. You just want to copy data verbatim - and a `Stream` is fine for that.

Comment: "Never, ever read arbitrary binary data as if it's text" - if you say almost never I agree.  But I've seen cases where it's useful, e.g. sending messages over a serial port that consist of control characters and ASCII text.  In this case it can be easier to deal with the message as a string.

Answer (score 1):

With most encodings, including Encoding.ASCII, converting bytes to chars and back again will not give you back the same data.  For example, IIRC Encoding.ASCII maps all bytes in the range 128-255 to the '?' character.  Then when you convert back to bytes, they will all convert back to the same value.

An exception is the Latin1 aka ISO-8859-1 aka Code Page 28591 encoding, which will map all bytes with hex values are in the range 0-255 to the Unicode character with the same hex value.  The following should give the result you want:

```
Encoding e = Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);
// or either of the following is equivalent
// Encoding.GetEncoding("Latin1");
// Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");

char[] reslts = e.GetChars(br.ReadBytes((int)br.BaseStream.Length));
br.BaseStream.Position = 0;
File.WriteAllBytes((@"C:\TestFile\File2",e.GetBytes(reslts));
```

Nevertheless, unless you have a good reason to do so, I wouldn't convert bytes to chars in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Encoding is used to encode a string into bytes, then back into a string.

You are using it backwards, decoding something that wasn't a string to begin with.